# Pivot mysql table returns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot a mysql table that is created like so

```
'CREATE TABLE `fundreturns` (
`Timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`FundName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`MonthYear` datetime NOT NULL,
`Returns` decimal(9,7) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`FundName`,`MonthYear`),
CONSTRAINT `FundName` FOREIGN KEY (`FundName`) REFERENCES `fundnames` (`fund_name`))
```

So that the result will be a table that looks like

```
Date    Company 1   Company 2   ...Company 200  
-------------------------------------------------
09/18        {Returns                    }              
07/18
```

Not every company has a return for every month, and it is a single percentage figure, does not need to be added up across the month. I have been looking for solutions using mysql or php, I have come across answers about dynamic sql statements and have tried using

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;

SET @sql_dynamic = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
                'IF(fundname = '''
                , fundname
                , ''', returns, NULL) AS '
                , fundname
            )
        )
    FROM fundreturns
);

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT monthyear, ', 
              @sql_dynamic, ' 
           FROM fundreturns
           GROUP BY monthyear'
       );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

which gives me an error

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ACL) Alternative Fund,IF(fundname = 'ABCA Reversion', fundreturns, NULL) AS ABC' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I cannot see ACL in your table

Comment: You mention PHP, so it's incomprehensible to me why you would attempt to solve this in MySQL.

Comment: I'm open to using whatever method would work, I would use PHP too. ACL is a company name in the table.

Comment: So it's missing inverted commas. But PHP surely offers a better solution.

Comment: After adding the commas, the majority of values are missing, there seems to only be one value per date. The PHP methods I've seen pretty much seem to need this query

Comment: Fixed by adding max( at if(fundname, returns a result that is what I was looking for. How would I execute this block from a PHP script?

Comment: `SELECT @sql;` so we _and you_ can see the erroneous statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
<?php

/*
CREATE TABLE fundreturns (
Timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
FundName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Returns decimal(9,7) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`FundName`,`Timestamp`)
);


INSERT INTO fundreturns VALUES
('2018-01-01','Piggy',10.2),
('2018-01-02','Piggy',15.1),
('2018-01-03','Piggy',7.4),
('2018-01-04','Piggy',3.9),
('2018-01-05','Piggy',1.2),

('2018-01-01','Kermit',10.5),
('2018-01-02','Kermit',9.9),
('2018-01-03','Kermit',10.5),
('2018-01-04','Kermit',11.9),
('2018-01-05','Kermit',12.2);


SELECT Timestamp
     , FundName
     , Returns
  FROM fundreturns
 ORDER
    BY timestamp
     , fundname;

+---------------------+----------+------------+
| Timestamp           | FundName | Returns    |
+---------------------+----------+------------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | Kermit   | 10.5000000 |
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | Piggy    | 10.2000000 |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | Kermit   |  9.9000000 |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | Piggy    | 15.1000000 |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | Kermit   | 10.5000000 |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | Piggy    |  7.4000000 |
| 2018-01-04 00:00:00 | Kermit   | 11.9000000 |
| 2018-01-04 00:00:00 | Piggy    |  3.9000000 |
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 | Kermit   | 12.2000000 |
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 | Piggy    |  1.2000000 |
+---------------------+----------+------------+
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT Timestamp
     , FundName
     , Returns
  FROM fundreturns
 ORDER
    BY timestamp
     , fundname;
";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = $row;
}

foreach($array as $v){
$new_array[$v['Timestamp']][$v['FundName']] = $v['Returns'];
}


print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [2018-01-01 00:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Kermit] => 10.5000000
            [Piggy] => 10.2000000
        )

    [2018-01-02 00:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Kermit] => 9.9000000
            [Piggy] => 15.1000000
        )

    [2018-01-03 00:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Kermit] => 10.5000000
            [Piggy] => 7.4000000
        )

    [2018-01-04 00:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Kermit] => 11.9000000
            [Piggy] => 3.9000000
        )

    [2018-01-05 00:00:00] => Array
        (
            [Kermit] => 12.2000000
            [Piggy] => 1.2000000
        )

)
```