# PHP/MySQL: How to transpose specific columns of database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table like this :

```
ID NAME    MODULE       SITUATION
1  morad   M1           YES
1  morad   M2           NO
4  anas    M1           YES
4  anas    M2           YES
2  sofia   M1           NO
2  sofia   M2           NO
```

I want to transpose data like this using PHP/MySQL.

```
ID NAME   M1  M2
1  morad  YES NO
4  anas   YES YES
2  sofia  NO  NO
```

Comment: `SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(CASE WHEN MODULE='M1' THEN SITUATION END) AS M1,  MAX(CASE WHEN MODULE='M2' THEN SITUATION END) AS M2 FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID, NAME` https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ug2e3zAUSSw3uYZktnGNd/0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425297/pivot-mysql-table-returns/52425955#52425955

Comment: @Nick Thank you, can I use another function, the max function give me NULL in M1 M2 colums. In my real table I have 3 case of SITUATION column V,NI,1.

Comment: @learner123 I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean. Can you edit the dbfiddle to show the problem and post a new one in the comments here?

Comment: @Nick can you see this screenshot please https://pasteboard.co/Ievip8E.png

Comment: @learner123 without seeing the raw table data as well the output doesn't mean anything. It's obviously a big table, but perhaps if you put a limit on it you can still demonstrate the problem.